# Other way to check keys of a Map other than containsKey

Tags: java, dictionary, uri

I created a method that returns a Map containing the parameters of an URI. Is there other way to check if key is already in Map other than map.containsKey(value)???

```
 public static Map <String,Object> UriMap(String uri){
    Map <String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();     
    String [] pathAndQuery = uri.split("\\?",2);    

    if(pathAndQuery.length == 2){//processing starts only if the size of pathAndQuery is 2
        String [] query = pathAndQuery[1].split("\\&");//split the string to array of Strings
        for(String str: query){
            if(str.contains("=")){
                String [] keysAndValues = str.split("\\=",2);                   
                if(map.containsKey(keysAndValues[0])){
                    String oldValue = map.get(keysAndValues[0]).toString();     
                    map.remove(keysAndValues[0]);
                    map.put(keysAndValues[0],Arrays.asList(oldValue, keysAndValues[1]));//for parameters listed twice put a list to value                                       
                }else{                                  
                    map.put(keysAndValues[0],keysAndValues[1]);//put a String to a map
                }
            }else{
                String newParameter = str;
                map.put(newParameter,"");//if "=" symbol is missing I put empty string for value
            }
        }
    }

    return map;
}
```

Comment: Why do you don't use the URI class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)? It provides all of the functionality you desire.

Comment: The URI Class doesn't return the Query Params parsed, it just returns the String after the '?' when using getQuery() method. He would still need to parse it manually

Answer (score 0):

Your way is not too bad but you are forgetting to unescape query string values.
Something like:

```
String value = URLDecoder.decode(keysAndValues[0], "UTF-8");
```

because for example characters like "?", "=" or "&" are escaped.

One optimization that you can do in your code is to not use split, but use indexOf.
So you don't create array with split but and you don't cycle on the same values two times.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use [Apache HTTP Components Library](http://hc.apache.org/). The "client" library has a [parse method](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html#parse%28java.net.URI,%20java.lang.String%29) which receives an URI (as a String or as a URI Instance) and gives you back a List of NameValuePairs.

The method is

```
org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.parse(String s, Charset charset);
```

or

```
org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.parse(URI uri, String encoding);
```

Also I think you'd like to convert your URI string to an URI Instance using Java [URI Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) String constructor first because if the URI is not well formed the constructor will throw a URISyntaxException "If the given string violates RFC 2396, as augmented by the above deviations".

Answer (score 0):

I just realized nobody answered what you asked for. This is embarrassing, however I think my previous answer can be helpful to somebody over time, so I decided to make a new answer.

Since your Map is a HashMap, It is able to tell if it contains a key in constant time O(1), so I guess a straight answer to your question would be:

Yes, there are other -naive- ways for checking if a key is already in your map, like looping over the keySet and comparing, however what you are doing is the best option.

The following is from the [HashMap documentation for Java6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

> This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets. Iteration over collection views requires time proportional to the "capacity" of the HashMap instance (the number of buckets) plus its size (the number of key-value mappings). Thus, it's very important not to set the initial capacity too high (or the load factor too low) if iteration performance is important.